# Does Mobile App to Crashlytics uses TLS 1.2?

Tags: crashlytics, fabric.io, fabric-answers

I believe the crash data is sent to Crashlytics using their REST APIs.

***Does the connection from Mobile App to Crashlytics uses TLS 1.2 and 2Way SSL ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. We use TLS 1.2 whenever possible. For older devices that may not support sending via TLS 1.2, then 1.1 or 1.0 will be used.